# How do I change the font on my Squarespace Nav Bar to custom font?

Tags: css, navigation, navbar, squarespace

I've recently uploaded a custom font to my squarespace page (Bedford Template) and, as I'm applying it through the sit, am having a hard time with the nav bar.

For the items that are Links are the nav bar, I can change the font with:

```
    #headerNav nav a {
    font-family: 'Vitesse-Sans' !important;
    }
```

But the items that are folders, not links, won't change.  I can't find the code to change the folder text!

Here's our site: https://www.asapasap.org/

Thank you!

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a very similar CSS rule, but to target the `.folder-toggle` class instead, like this:

```
#headerNav nav .folder-toggle {
  font-family: 'Vitesse-Sans';
}
```

If you haven't already, consider familiarizing yourself with [browser developer tools/web inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#The_Inspector_DOM_explorer_and_CSS_editor) (often opened with the F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+I keys). With it, you'd be able to explore the existing CSS rules applied to your site and experiment with the best ways to override them.

Comment: Hey there -  So you're advice was great!  Fixed the folder problem, and allowed me to apply the same font throughout the site!   There's just one item that I can't identify with the web inspector, and can't find any answer online either:  How might I change the banner font at the top of each page.  I.e. "ABOUT" on this page: https://www.asapasap.org/about-asap

Comment: It seems you sorted out your additional question, but for good measure: via web inspector, you can see that the rule would be something like `.desc-wrapper p > strong {font-family: 'Vitesse-Sans';}`.